# Justified text with predefined line breaks

Tags: line-breaking

I want to set a text following the line breaks in a certain edition, and I want it to be justified. I suppose I should use `\obeylines`, but don't know how to get the lines justified.

Comment: I think that adding `\linebreak` at the desired places is easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more testing with actual text and the desired pagination parameters would be needed, but this should be a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{originalbreaks}[1]
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mbox{}\linebreak}%
  \hbadness10000 % turn off warnings
  \catcode`\^^M=\active#1}
 {\unskip\unpenalty\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.

\begin{originalbreaks}
Some text where we want to preserve the original
breaks, even if this leads to very bad
typesetting.
\end{originalbreaks}

Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.
Some text with normal justification.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is similar to `\obeyspaces`, but instead of making the end-of-line character equivalent to `\par`, I make it into `\mbox{}\linebreak`. Note `\mbox{}`, so an empty line in input will leave a blank line in output; this can be avoided by using explicitly `\par%` where a paragraph break is wanted.

At the end a space is removed (if it sneaked in) and `\unpenalty` will remove the trailing `\linebreak`. The `\hbadness10000` bit is for avoiding irrelevant messages about underfull boxes (you *know* there will be). The first token in the environment is absorbed as an argument in order to avoid the end-of-line after `\begin{originalbreaks}` to be turned into `\mbox{}\linebreak`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, flawless!

Comment: Thanks! could I bother you to add some comments to the code? in particular, I don't understand what the ~ and the #1 are about.